# How to align rotation of a triangle to a rectangle in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, alignment

I created a rectangle and a triangle using the polygon tool.  When I created the triangle the rotation of the triangle was arbitrary, so I have the following situation:

[image]

How can I make the rotation of the triangle align with the rectangle so it makes a perfect arrow shape similar to:

[image]

I try selecting the triangle and rotating it but then I'm just aligning it visually and I'd like to do it precisely so the left edge of the triangle is perfectly vertical.  I tried using the transform tool but the rotation degree seems to be relative to its current angle so that doesn't really help me (unless I'm misunderstanding it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After clicking the polygon tool and selecting the number of corners, while dragging on the canvas press Ctrl key, so that it snaps the triangle (kind of equilateral triangle where base is horizontal). Now selecting the triangle with the selection tool, click on rotate selection 90 deg clockwise (short key-CTRL+ ] ) from the control panel which gives you a precise left edged triangle.
If its created without snapping (the first step without holding Ctrl key), then the triangle still can be rotated with precised edge on the left. To do this you need to activate snapping options.

[image: rotate]

Comment: Thank you that works well, still curious is it possible to do this after the triangle has already been created with some random rotation?

Comment: Yes it can be done. Edited my answer. To do this you need to activate snapping options and use ruler. Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Are you just eye balling the move of the triangle's rotation center to the corner of the triangle or does it somehow snap to that corner?

Comment: The cross hair that is the triangle's center will snap to the corner, if snap to cusp nodes is enabled. But when rotated I observed that the other end of the triangle does not snap to the guide. You need to zoom and rotate it later for precise adjustment.

Comment: The first method works for me but I can't get the 2nd method to work as far as snapping (but I haven't used snapping in Inkscape yet)

Comment: You can have a look at it to know more about how snapping works  -http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Snapping.html